# Registering dynamic vuex modules vs new Classes

Tags: vuejs2, vuex, vuex-modules

I wrote a simple Vue/Vuex app for my company that is basically a data entry form. It collects information on a person, their vehicle, etc. The person portion of the form has over 20 data points, spread out over 4 children components and one sibling component, using Vuex to handle state.

My company wants to extend the app so it can capture major reports that can consist of multiple people. Coming from an OOP background, my first thought is to create a class and new up a person whenever one is added. I've been reading about dynamic modules in Vuex, which seems to be Vue's answer to classes, but there are some things I'm struggling with understanding.

If I register multiple "person" modules in the parent component (one after the other), how will the children components know which person they're referring to? Will the referenced person still have to be passed down through props? If so, that defeats the purpose of the store, no?

Am I missing something here? Because to me it seems easier to create a new person, fill the data through props/emit and push the completed person object into the store for later use.

I know there are multiple ways of doing something, but I'm just trying to understand the hows and whys and better learn Vue (and javascript in general).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think dynamic modules is a replacement for class, and I don't think you can register duplicated modules. 
Use a list in store to hold an array of Person would be the right way in my opinion.